# Run a local bat file from javascript with HTA

Tags: javascript, vba, hta

I made a `.bat` file and I wish to run it with a link's url as parameter using Javascript.

This is what I have:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "downloader",
  title: "Download reference",
  contexts: ["link"]
});
```

this is for registering a Firefox context menu element and

```
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  console.log("clicked on meh yo");
  if(info.menuItemId === "downloader"){
    // adding a new script element
    var filename = info.linkText;
    var fileurl = info.linkUrl;
    var x = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    x.setAttribute("language", "VBScript");
    // calling a vbscript that will call my bat file with the parameters
    var t = document.createTextNode("Set WshShell = CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\");WshShell.Run \"C:/Users/name/Documents/Commands/get-content.bat " + fileurl + " " + filename + "\"");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    console.log("ref was saved yo");
  }
});
```

The HTA script is in a form of a simple text which is added to the website's original html.

Note this is a tool for myself, it has to work only on my machine.

The problem is that I get the console logs but nothing happens. I tested my bat file (using cmd) and it works fine so the problem should be with my javascript here.

Comment: VBScript is only supported by Internet Explorer for local files and intranets **only**.

Comment: `var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

Comment: Thanks, in that case I think I have to find a different solution (than running a script from local file system).

Comment: You aren't allowed to run WshShell commands from pages on the internet - that applies to any language incl JavaScript (the code above is JavaScript equivalent of VBscript using the WScript.Shell object). Perhaps step back and layout what the problem you are trying to solve is.